# 100% width item only one side

Tags: html, css

I need to add a background colour to my quote-box only on right side (beyond the container). Quote-box is in container. I was trying `position: absolute`, but it didn't work as well. Is it possible to do it easy way? Oh, I'm using Bootstrap 4.

What I want:
[image]

My code:

```css
.quote-box {
  background-color: #fbe6ff;
  padding: 65px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.quote-text {
  color: #111;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.quote-author {
  color: #666;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 23px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div data-brackets-id="5087" class="quote">
      <div data-brackets-id="5088" class="row">
        <div data-brackets-id="5089" class="col-lg-12 quote-box text-center">
          <div data-brackets-id="5090" class="w-75 mx-auto">
            <h2 data-brackets-id="5091" class="quote-text">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's</h2>
            <p data-brackets-id="5092" class="quote-author">- bbc.com</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the `container` to `container-fluid` and given a `margin-left` to it.
Also specified `overflow-x:hidden` caused due to the margin.

```css
.quote-box {
        background-color: #fbe6ff;
        padding-top: 65px;
        padding-bottom: 65px;
        border-radius: 20px;
    }
    .quote-text {
        color: #111;
        font-size: 40px;
        font-weight: 300;
    }
    .quote-author {
        color: #666;
        font-weight: 300;
        font-size: 23px;
    }
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body  style="overflow-x:hidden;">
<div class="container-fluid" style="margin-left:30px;">
<div data-brackets-id="5087" class="quote">
                <div data-brackets-id="5088" class="row">
                    <div data-brackets-id="5089" class="col-lg-12 quote-box text-center">
                        <div data-brackets-id="5090" class="w-75 mx-auto">
                        <h2 data-brackets-id="5091" class="quote-text">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's</h2>
                        <p data-brackets-id="5092" class="quote-author">- bbc.com</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</div>
</body>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `margin-left` property, see if that gets you what you want. If not, try `position: absolute` again and also use the `left` property.

Answer (score 0):

You can use css for it. just apply your desired bg-color to the body element and then keep your quotebox in another container inside of body element and also set width of quotebox to 100%.